# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) while running this piece of code written in java script in google chrome console

Tags: javascript

I want to create a program in java script using a function while is given name check() 
if the age enter by user is = 18 it says Cong its your first ride and if age>18 it should say powering on and if both conditions is not there there then it display Not qualify for ride but as i run code in google chrome console its gives me this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) 
Here is the code below:

```
var age=prompt("What is your age=");
function check(age){
    if (Number(age)===18){
        console.log("Cong its your first ride");
    }
    else if(Number(age)>18){
        console.log("Powering On");
    }
    else(){
        console.log("Not qualify for ride");
    }
}
check(age);
```

Comment: Else does not take a brace(). And I don't even think this question is eligible for SO. This is such a basic criteria which you should have checked before posting.

Comment: Voting to close: **why is this code not working**?

Comment: You could have tried to understand the problem a bit before posting... Chrome console allows you to see the origin of the problem just by clicking on the line number in the error line.

Answer (score 1):

`else` block does not have `()`

```js
var age=prompt("What is your age=");
function check(age){
    if (Number(age)===18){
        console.log("Cong its your first ride");
    }
    else if(Number(age)>18){
        console.log("Powering On");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Not qualify for ride");
    }
}
check(age);
```

Comment: I believe this question doesn't need an answer, that's why I downvoted

Comment: @Ivan - I wanted to add the working version that is why avoided the comment. Thanks mate for sharing your reason for dv. :)

Answer (score -1):

`else()` having unnecessary brackets, try

```js
    var age=prompt("What is your age=");
    function check(age){
        if (Number(age)===18){
            console.log("Cong its your first ride");
        }
        else if(Number(age)>18){
            console.log("Powering On");
        }
        else{
            console.log("Not qualify for ride");
        }
    }
    check(age);
```